# Big oh Analysis

Tags: python-3.x, big-o

Code 1:

I my opinion this code is O(n^3) since the outer loop runs n^2 times and the inner loop runs n times. According to my prof this code is not O(n^3). Could someone please explain why? I am really confused.

```
i, j, sum = 1, 1, 0

while i < n**3:
  while j < n:
     sum = sum + i
     j += 1
  i = i + n
```

Code 2:

I think this code is O(n). Could someone please confirm?

```
i, j, sum = 0, 0, 0

while i ** 2 < n:
  while j ** 2 < n:
     sum += i*j
     j += 2
  i += 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i, j, sum = 1, 1, 0

while i < n**3:
  while j < n:
     sum = sum + i
     j += 1
  i = i + n
```

Note that the inner loop is executed only during the first pass of the outer loop, because `j` is not reinitialized as in `for` loop. It is pretty obvious that the running time of the inner loop is exactly `n`. On the other hand, outer loop is executed `n^2` times. Why? Watch how `i` changes: first it is `1`, then `n+1`, then `2n+1`, ..., and finally `n^2*n+1`, so `i` gets incremented `n^2` times. Therefore, the total running time is `n + n^2`, which is `O(n^2)`.

```
i, j, sum = 0, 0, 0

while i ** 2 < n:
  while j ** 2 < n:
     sum += i*j
     j += 2
  i += 4
```

Similar analysis as in the first case, with the additional remark that the condition `while i ** 2 < n` is equivalent to `while i < sqrt(n)`. Inner loop is executed only during the first pass of the outer loop and its running time is `sqrt(n) / 2` because `j` gets incremented by 2 (not by 1). Outer loop runs `sqrt(n) / 4` times, so the total running time is `sqrt(n) / 2 + sqrt(n) / 4`, which is `O(sqrt(n))`.